# Self in Class Demanding Argument

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, self, typeerror

For some reason most instances of classes are returning Type errors saying that insufficient arguments were passed, the problem is with self.
This works fine:

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, some_message):
        self.message = some_message
        print ("New ExampleClass instance created, with message:")
        print (self.message)
ex = ExampleClass("message")
```

However almost every other Class I define and call an instance of returns the same error. The almost identical function:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.defaultmsg = "message"
    def say(self):
        print(self.defaultmsg)
test = Test
test.say()
```

Returns a Type Error, saying that it needs an argument. I'm getting this problem not just with that class, but with  pretty much every class I define, and I have no idea what the problem is. I just updated python, but was getting the error before. I'm fairly new to programming.

Answer (score 4):

You have to instantiate the class:

```
test = Test()   #test is an instance of class Test
```

instead of

```
test = Test     #test is the class Test
test.say()      #TypeError: unbound method say() must be called with Test instance as first argum ent (got nothing instead)
```

if you are curious you can try this:

```
test = Test
test.say(Test())     #same as Test.say(Test())
```

It works because I gave the class instance (self) to the unbound method !
Absolutely not recommended to code this way.

Comment: My first thought: `test = Test; test.say(test())`

Answer (score 2):

You should add parentheses to instantiate a class:

```
test = Test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test refers to the class itself, rather than an instance of that class.  To create an actual test instance, or to 'instantiate' it, add the parentheses.  For example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   pass
... 
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0xa2eb50>
```

The error message was trying to tell you that there was no such `self` object to pass in (implicitly) as the function argument, because in your case `test.say` would be an unbound method.